# LINQ .equals() and string variables

Tags: .net, oracle, linq

Not sure why this query returns no results (note that `CUSTOMERs` is from an Oracle database):

```
string zip = "12345"
string state = "MA"

var result = from x in CUSTOMERs
             where x.STATE.Equals(state) || x.ZIP.Equals(zip)
             select x;
```

But this one does?

```
var result = from x in CUSTOMERs
             where x.STATE.Equals("MA") || x.ZIP.Equals("12345")
             select x;
```

Comment: Unable to replicate the behavior described.  What specific debugging have you done to confirm this?  What specifically is `CUSTOMERs`?

Comment: I'm doing this in LinqPad, not sure how to debug there? CUSTOMERs is an Oracle database.

Comment: If you try in an actual application, what happens?  (Just to narrow down the possibility of a problem with LinqPad.)  And what *specifically* is `CUSTOMERs`.  What is the type of that variable, what does it contain, etc.

Comment: This is mostly due to creation of Expression Tree in the IQueryable syntax, which is not able to bind / parse the variables

Answer (score 1):

Following is my understanding, you are using a `Oracle data connector` in the `LinqPad`, which allows you to Query a Customers Table, now since you are running an `IQueryable<T> Linq Query`, which unlike `Linq to Objects`, execute at the remote data source and takes an Expression tree in the form `Expression<Func<T,bool>`. It is not able to bind the values when supply a variable instead of actual hard coded value. Issue with binding values is purely due to the way it expects and parse the Expression tree internally.

To verify my point, check the signature of `CUSTOMERs.Where` in the Fluent syntax and it would be taking an expression tree instead of `Func<T,bool>` required by the Linq2Objects

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I'm not sure that I fully understand this. Is there a workaround to get this to work in LinqPad?

Comment: Can you try the following if it works:

`const string zip = "12345"`
`const string state = "MA"`

Comment: What I am suggesting is, since the query is translated by the data connector for the database server to process, chances are it is not able to translate the variables, when query is generated, you might have to check their documentation to see, as they may have a different mechanism to bind like placeholders. Btw which data connector are you using.

Comment: Yes, using the `const string` does work. But I was hoping to use a parameter that was passed in. Oh well. BTW, I am using the `Open Access Driver`. Thanks for your help with this @Mrinal Kamboj.